# TCP server and client at once

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am trying to create a blockchain example where all clients work as a server and a client at once. I have a thread which constantly listens for incoming connections and when a client is accepted, it creates a thread which reads the incoming data and sends data aswell. It works one way, for example if just one server is started and I join to it as a client, but for example I want to start 3 instances and start a server on all 3 of them, and then I want to connect to instance 2 from instance 1 and so on...  This is the code for acceping clients and the join, host function:

```
TcpClient Join() 
        {
            int server_port = int.Parse(port.Text); 
            klient = new TcpClient(); 

            try
            {
                klient.Connect("localhost", server_port); 
                if (klient.Connected) //Če se poveže
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected to server."); 
                    myNetworkStream = klient.GetStream();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }

            return klient;
        }
```

```
TcpListener Host()
        {
            int port = FreeTcpPort();
            IPAddress ip_address = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"); //parsing ipja
            TcpListener host = new TcpListener(ip_address, port);//ustvari listener
            label1.Text = port.ToString();
            try
            {
                host.Start();//zagon strežnika
                Console.WriteLine("Server started..."); 
                mine_button.Enabled = true;
                Sprejemaj_cliente = new Thread(Cakaj_na_clienta); 
                Sprejemaj_cliente.Start(host); 
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); 
            }

            return host;
        }
```

```
public void Cakaj_na_clienta(object argument) 
        {
            TcpListener host = (TcpListener)argument; 
            try
            {
                while (true) //ČAKANJE NA POŠILJATELJA
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client...");
                    TcpClient client = host.AcceptTcpClient();
                    klient = client;
                    MessageBox.Show("Client connected");
                    string odjemalec_IP = ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString(); 
                    int odjemalec_PORT = ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Port; 
                    Console.WriteLine("Povezal se je pošiljatelj na naslovu " + odjemalec_IP + ":" + odjemalec_PORT); //Zagon strežnika
                    myNetworkStream = klient.GetStream();
                    sync_thread = new Thread(Synchronize);  
                    sync_thread.Start();
                    send_chain = new Thread(Send_Chain);
                    send_chain.Start();

                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have two network layers 1) Application Layer 2)TCP transport layer.  The terminology for client and server are different in the two layers.  TCP the listener (which is the server) starts first and waits for a client to connect.  In net the listener can accept more than one client (from different machines) using the same port number.  You application layer you want the server to forward messages receive from one client and forward to other clients.  I do not think you want each client to send to all the others.It would be better if each client was to send to all others to use UDP broadcast.

Comment: It's not very clear what it is you're trying to do.  It sounds like you want a full mesh between all the "systems".  Each system is doing something (eg a calculation) and if it finds the result it communicates that to every other system.  Have I understood that correctly?